# Is there a way to turn off duplex mode using NetNamedPipeBinding (IDuplexSessionChannel is not supported)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simple .NET (C#) application with three threads: Main thread and two spawned by the Main one. The first child is used to initialize and start the **ServiceHost** instance using **IFirstService** contract to operate. The second one is a kind of a client which uses **ChannelFactory** to create a channel for communication with the **FirstService** thread. **NetNamedPipeBinding** is used for this channel.

After starting the application by executing

```
mono application.exe
```

Expected output should be

```
Using System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding...
FirstService Host is opened
Hello from Second Thread
FirstService Host is closed
```

But the actual result is

```
Using System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding...
FirstService Host is opened
NamedPipeChannelListener.OnAcceptChannel
NamedPipeChannelListener.OnAcceptChannel.2
NamedPipeChannelListener.OnAcceptChannel.3
NamedPipeChannelListener.OnAcceptChannel
System.InvalidOperationException: Channel type IDuplexSessionChannel is not supported.
at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime runtime, System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription contract, System.TimeSpan openTimeout, System.TimeSpan closeTimeout, System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannel contextChannel, System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannelFactory factory, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion messageVersion, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress, System.Uri via) [0x00165] in <8cdac92fdd4b495ba10570db10926ad4>:0
at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory channelFactory, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress, System.Uri via) [0x0002c] in <8cdac92fdd4b495ba10570db10926ad4>:0
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel].CreateChannel (System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address, System.Uri via) [0x0005b] in <8cdac92fdd4b495ba10570db10926ad4>:0
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel].CreateChannel (System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address) [0x00000] in <8cdac92fdd4b495ba10570db10926ad4>:0
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel].CreateChannel () [0x00012] in <8cdac92fdd4b495ba10570db10926ad4>:0
at WcfNamedPipeBindingTest.MainClass.SecondPointThread (System.Object binding_info) [0x00041] in <ef4f03ef8ba048f3b924916715fa960b>:0
FirstService Host is closed
```

### Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace WcfNamedPipeBindingTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IFirstService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void ShowMessage (string message);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior (InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    class FirstService : IFirstService
    {
        public void ShowMessage (string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (message);
        }
    }

    class BindingInfo
    {
        public Binding binding;
        public Uri uri;
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            try {

                var binding_info = new BindingInfo {
                    binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding (),
                    uri = new Uri ("net.pipe://localhost/ftest")
                };


                Console.WriteLine ("Using {0}...", binding_info.binding.ToString ());

                var first_point = new Thread (FirstPointThread);
                var second_point = new Thread (SecondPointThread);

                first_point.Start (binding_info);
                second_point.Start (binding_info);

                first_point.Join ();
                second_point.Join ();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex);
            }
        }

        public static void FirstPointThread (object binding_info)
        {
            try {
                var binding = ((BindingInfo)binding_info).binding;
                var uri = ((BindingInfo)binding_info).uri;

                var instance = new FirstService ();
                var host = new ServiceHost (instance, uri);
                host.AddServiceEndpoint (typeof(IFirstService), binding, "fserv");

                host.Opened += (sender, e) => {
                    Console.WriteLine ("FirstService Host is opened");
                    Thread.Sleep (5000);
                    ((ServiceHost)sender).Close ();
                };

                host.Closed += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine ("FirstService Host is closed");

                host.Open ();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex);
            }
        }

        public static void SecondPointThread (object binding_info)
        {
            try {
                var binding = ((BindingInfo)binding_info).binding;
                var uri = ((BindingInfo)binding_info).uri;

                Thread.Sleep (2000);

                var pipe_factory =
                    new ChannelFactory<IFirstService> (
                        binding,
                        new EndpointAddress (
                            string.Format ("{0}/fserv", uri)
                        )
                    );

                pipe_factory.Open ();
                IFirstService pipe_channel = pipe_factory.CreateChannel ();
                pipe_channel.ShowMessage ("Hello from Second Thread");
                pipe_factory.Close ();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I avoid using of a DuplexSessionChannel?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using named pipes for WCF (which use MMFs as part of their implementation) are not available with Mono.

However, you might be able to use `NetTcpBinding` with Mono. Try changing your binding to the following:

```
var binding_info = new BindingInfo
{
    binding = new NetTcpBinding(),
    uri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost/ftest")
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I wonder then what do those messages from MONO framework mean?

    `NamedPipeChannelListener.OnAcceptChannel`
    `NamedPipeChannelListener.OnAcceptChannel.2`
    `NamedPipeChannelListener.OnAcceptChannel.3`
    `NamedPipeChannelListener.OnAcceptChannel`


Is it related to a not fully implemented feature?